# Проблема с subscription при schema stitching в apollo server

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Помогите найти ошибку как правильно подключить subscription при schema stitching.

Использую [apollo-server-express](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-express) для graphql back-end. В нём планирую обрабатывать только mutations, а query и subscription перенаправить на [hasura](https://hasura.io/) с помощью schema stitching c интроспекцией. Query через apollo-server к hasura отрабатывают нормально и возвращают ожидаемые данные.

А вот subscription не работают и я получаю вот такую ошибку: " Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field subscription_root.users"
[image: error logs graphql from server]

При чем на сам сервер hasura ивенты приходят:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но apollo-server возмущается на ответ от hasura. Не первый день мучаюсь и не могу понять в чем проблема.

В самом редакторе hasura подписки работают.

```
import {
  introspectSchema,
  makeExecutableSchema,
  makeRemoteExecutableSchema,
  mergeSchemas,
  transformSchema,
  FilterRootFields
} from 'graphql-tools';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import { hasRoleResolver } from './directives';
import { typeDefs } from './types';
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws';
import { split } from 'apollo-link';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities';
import { SubscriptionClient } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';
import * as ws from 'ws';
import { OperationTypeNode } from 'graphql';

interface IDefinitionsParams {
  operation?: OperationTypeNode,
  kind: 'OperationDefinition' | 'FragmentDefinition'
}

const wsurl = 'ws://graphql-engine:8080/v1alpha1/graphql';

const getWsClient = function (wsurl: string) {
  const client = new SubscriptionClient(wsurl, {
    reconnect: true,
    lazy: true
  }, ws);
  return client;
};

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(getWsClient(wsurl));

const createRemoteSchema = async () => {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://graphql-engine:8080/v1alpha1/graphql',
    fetch: (nodeFetch as any)
  });

  const link = split(
    ({ query }) => {
      const { kind, operation }: IDefinitionsParams = getMainDefinition(query);
      console.log('kind = ', kind, 'operation = ', operation);
      return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
    },
    wsLink,
    httpLink,
  );

  const remoteSchema = await introspectSchema(link);
  const remoteExecutableSchema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    link,
    schema: remoteSchema
  });

  const renamedSchema = transformSchema(
    remoteExecutableSchema,
    [
      new FilterRootFields((operation, fieldName) => {
        return (operation === 'Mutation') ? false : true; //  && fieldName === 'password'
      })
    ]
  );
  return renamedSchema;
};

export const createNewSchema = async () => {
  const hasuraExecutableSchema = await createRemoteSchema();
  const apolloSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    directiveResolvers: {
      hasRole: hasRoleResolver
    }
  });
  return mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [
      hasuraExecutableSchema,
      apolloSchema
    ]
  });
};
```

[Ссылка на код](https://codepen.io/OLDIN_/project/editor/ZQKNnb#)

Если нужны какие-то дополнительные данные - предоставлю.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил установкой graphql-tools 4-й версии. Оказывается редактор даже не заметил что у меня нету этой зависимость и просто брал и node_modules ту версию, которую установил какой-то другой пакет. Проблемная версия 3.x.
[Pull request](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/pull/928/commits/39e98f1112cf6cc10867845b15eab6295f4ebe40) где ошибка была исправлена